# iOS - Tab bar UIWebView

Tags: ios, tabs

Pretty new to iOS development - so this may be easier than I think.

Situation:
When creating a new tab bar application, it creates a MainWindows.xib and a FirstView.xib

Problem:
I want to put in a UIWebView in the First Tab and have written the code for it. I have seen plenty of Youtube Vids and tutorials, but they seem to load the UIViews into the MainWindows.xib - maybe an older version??

What I have done:
I have named the IBOutlet - Home // IBOutlet UIWebView *Home;
I have also told in the .m file where the UIWebview should go to once loaded (google.com)
Now in interface builder if I select the first tab bar, I can see the "home" in my outlet section and I need to link that to my FirstView.

How do I do that??? when I clock on the circle, or control-click, it does not want to select the UIWebView in another .xib file.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers Jeff

---

It does not seem to work - the class is in a different xib file, so I cant drag it across??

Answer (score 0):

Open FirstView.xib in Interface Builder, from left pane in Objects list select View, open Utilities pane (3 icons with different view layouts, located in upper right corner of Xcode, it says View underneath, Utilities is on right). Switch to Identity inspector tab and change class to UIWebView. Then just add new outlet to FirstViewController and connect web view to Files owner .view outlet.

Comment: It does not seem to work - the class is in a different xib file, so I cant drag it across??

Comment: @Jeffwk82 Classes are not in xibs. In that class dropdown you can choose any class from the project. If by chance class is missing in the list, type its name. In this case you want to have UIWebView in first tab and you already have code in FirstView.m, which is subclass used by FirstView(Controller).xib (which also equals view controller used on first tab). If that's not the case, make it so. If that's not what you wanted, reformulate your question. When conditions are met, proceed to do what I told you in my answer. You'll end up with UIWebView instead of UIView, loaded from FirstView.xib.